# Can't use std::for_each() and std::bind() to filter elements in a vector and put those filtered elements into a new vector

Tags: c++, vector, bind

Why doesn't the below code work when I'm trying to use `std::for_each()` and `std::bind()` to filter elements in a `vector` and put those filtered elements into a new `vector`?

```cpp
void mypred(int a, int b, vector<int>& c){
    if(a < b){
        cout <<"yes" << endl;
        c.push_back(a);
    }
}

int main(){
    vector<int> test = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    vector<int> final;
    final.reserve(10);
    for_each(test.begin(), test.end(), bind(mypred, placeholders::_1, 3, final));
    for(auto i = final.begin(); i != final.end(); i++){
        cout << *i << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code can only print out two `yes`. But nothing in the vector `final`.

Comment: `for_each(test.begin(), test.end(), bind(mypred, placeholders::_1, 3, final));` -> `for_each(test.begin(), test.end(), bind(mypred, placeholders::_1, 3, std::ref(final)));`

Comment: Why not use a lambda instead of `std::bind()`? `for_each(test.begin(), test.end(), [&](int a){ mypred(a, 3, final); });` Or, just get rid of `mypred()` altogether: `for_each(test.begin(), test.end(), [&](int a){ if (a < 3){ cout << "yes" << endl; final.push_back(a); } });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I know what's happened. Thanks for the help from @MikeVine.
`std::bind()` will use a copy rather than a reference of a parameter. So we need to add `std::ref()` to let it use a reference.